# SCCM 2012 R2 client deployment

Tags: deployment, sccm, agents

I just installed SCCM 2012 R2 (thx Internet for tips) on a 2012 R2 server and i have a new problem to solve.

How can i deploy correctly agents on all clients of my lab ? 'cause when i click on "Install client" everything's good i can finish the installation but i see any changes on the Console Configuration Manager and on my server (i tried to install just on one server).

I tried to reboot all my servers, to change my installation mode :

"Allow the client software to be installed on domain controllers"

"Always install the client software"

"Install the client software from a specified site"

No change...

If someone has a tips for me to solve this problem i'll be recognizing.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you want to install Configuration Manager clients by using [Client Push Installation](http://Client%20Push%20Installation).

First, you need to add an user account to install client.

[image]

Then you Install Configuration Manager clients using Client Push Installation Wizard.

On the server side, The **ccm.log** records client push installation activities.

On the client side, if the ccm.log not report error, after few minutes when you login to client machine and look at the process tab in task manager you will see the **ccmsetup.exe** is running.

You can view the **ccmsetup.log** file on the client machine to check the log messages and monitor the client installation process.

When the installation is finished, you can see the Configuration Manager icon in the Control Panel.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.